# Create checkbox from kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, checkbox

I am making an app with kotlin, and I have two checkboxes, When I select the first checkbox, I would like 2 checkboxes to be automatically created in the next activity. if I select the second checkbox I would like 3 checkboxes to be created, and if I select the two checkboxes, I would like 5 checkboxes to be created in the next activity. Is that possible? and how.
Thanks.
This is my first activity.

```
    listo = findViewById(R.id.button4) as Button
    listo!!.setOnClickListener {
        var lista= arrayListOf<Int>()
        if(checkBox.isChecked){
            lista.add(1)
        }
        if(checkBox2.isChecked){
            lista.add(2)
        }
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity3::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("check", lista)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

My second activity would like it to be something like this, but I'm sure what I tried can't.

```
    texto3=findViewById(R.id.editTextDate)
    val extras = intent.extras
    val s = extras?.getIntegerArrayList("check")
    var cantidad= s?.size
    var i=0
    while (i< cantidad!!){
        when(s?.get(i)){
            1->create(<CheckBox
                            android:text="@string/string_check1"
                            android:onClick="evento"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/check+i"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                     />)
            2->create(<CheckBox
                            android:text="@string/string_check1"
                            android:onClick="evento"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/check+i"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                     />)
            else-> println("ERROR")
        }
        i++
    }
```

I would like the checkboxes to have the elements of my list as id.

Comment: We're not doing the work for you, what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I already modified it